# Pyspark Most expensive Product

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get the most expensive product using PySpark. I basically have to translate this query from SQL to pyspark:

```
%sql

SELECT product, item_price as price
FROM lotstemp
ORDER BY item_price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Can anyone help me to write this query in PySpark?

Comment: You can run that very same SQL query on Spark, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly run the sql in spark by registering the dataframe as temp table like

```
df.createOrReplaceTempTable('lotstemp')
df=spark.sql('SELECT product, item_price as price FROM lotstemp ORDER BY item_price DESC LIMIT 1')
```

or if you want to use dataframe API you can do this in following way:

```
df1 = df.orderBy(f.desc('State')).limit(1)
```

Hope it helps.